# Managing bound datagridview with a class?

Tags: vb.net

Sorry for the formulation, It's the first time thas I post a question here.

I would like to manage the datagridview + bindingnavigator with a class + implement textbox below the spread with values of the line selected.
This datagridview is bound with database's table.
I can fill the spread and implement textbox.

But, when I move in the spread with the arrows of the bindingnvigator, the contents of textbox are always late of a line with regard to the active line.
When I click in the spread and after I use the arrows, the synchronization is lost.

It's not easy to show all the code. There are many events.

Could you help me ?
Many thanks !
Luc-Emmanuel

My class:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class clsSpread
    Private dgv As DataGridView
    Private da As OleDbDataAdapter
    Private bs As BindingSource
    Private bn As BindingNavigator
    Private fconn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Alltraces_Network\Data\Alltraces_local_EDI.accdb")

Public Sub New(pDgv As DataGridView, pBn As BindingNavigator)

    dgv = pDgv
    bn = pBn
    bs = New BindingSource

End Sub

Public Sub pRefresh(pStrSql As String)

    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(pStrSql, fconn)
    Dim dt As New DataTable(pStrSql)

    da.Fill(dt)
    dgv.DataSource = dt

    bs.DataSource = dt
    bn.BindingSource = bs

End Sub

Public Sub bs_PositionChanged(pPosition As Integer)
    If pPosition < 0 Then Exit Sub
    dgv.CurrentCell = dgv(dgv.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex, pPosition)      'provoque l'event dgvCde_SelectionChanged

End Sub
```

On the form size:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim objdgvCde As clsSpread
    Dim objdgvCde_Item As clsSpread
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    strSql = "select idClient, idCde_Int, idCde_Client, XDock from qryCde_Client order by idClient"
    objdgvCde = New clsSpread(dgvCde, bnCde_Client)
    objdgvCde.pRefresh(strSql)

end sub

Private Sub dgvCde_CurrentCellChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dgvCde.CurrentCellChanged
    Dim intIdx%
    Dim strSql$
    Dim dgvRow As DataGridViewRow

    intIdx = dgvCde.CurrentRow.Index
    dgvRow = dgvCde.Rows(intIdx)

    txtIdCde_Int2.Text = dgvRow.Cells("idCde_Int").Value
end sub

Private Sub BindingNavigatorMoveNextItem1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BindingNavigatorMoveNextItem1.Click
    'move next
    Dim intIdx%
    intIdx = objdgvCde.Get_Row_Index
    objdgvCde.bs_PositionChanged(intIdx + 1)

End Sub

end class
```

Comment: `It's the first time thas I post a question here`  Which means you should read [ask] and take the [tour].  Also take the time to format your code as code so it can be read - make it easy for others to help you.  Also of interest will be [mcve] - we dont need all the code, just the broke part.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Whenever the code is too big to post, it's a good idea to make an [MCVE], as Plutonix mentioned. I learned how to make MCVEs before [SO] existed, because it's the *only* way to figure out what's wrong in a complex situation, whether you ask for help or do it yourself.

Comment: You lie!  How could code have existed before StackOverflow???  Where did they paste it from?

Comment: To be fair, I only started coding a year before SO's founding; but I didn't discover it until ~2010.

Comment: UI controls like a TextBox can be bound to a datasource just like the DGV can be.  If you do that you dont need any code to sync the TB